# WORKDIR does not create a directory

Tags: docker

Can you tell me why a directory has not been created in the container?

Here is the DockerFile

```
FROM node:16.13-alpine AS base

WORKDIR /usr/app/test/

RUN npm config set unsafe-perm true

COPY ./test/ .

FROM nginx:1.20-alpine
LABEL version="1.0"

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY ./test/dist/my-app/ .
```

I created an image, launched it, I go into it, but there is no directory there

```
/usr/app/test
```

There are no errors when creating an image:

```
Step 1/9 : FROM node:16.13-alpine AS base
 ---> 710c8aa630d5
Step 2/9 : WORKDIR /usr/app/test/
 ---> Running in dbe3994e667a
Removing intermediate container dbe3994e667a
 ---> 54b36120290d
Step 3/9 : RUN npm config set unsafe-perm true
 ---> Running in e301f90c084f
Removing intermediate container e301f90c084f
 ---> ca6dc8541ba5
Step 4/9 : COPY ./test/ .
 ---> e00bf919a630
```

Here's what's in the container:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Dockerfile is defining a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/), and what you are seeing is expected behavior.

Everything before the second `FROM`, so in this case `FROM nginx:1.20-alpine`, is discarded in the final image unless it's copied over.

If you want the first `WORKDIR` to persist in the final image, you need to explicitly copy over:

```
FROM node:16.13-alpine AS base
WORKDIR /usr/app/test/

FROM nginx:1.20-alpine
COPY --from=0 /usr/app/test /usr/app/test
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
```